# Deleting Chrome OS while having Linux mint?

Tags: linux-mint, kernel, linux-kernel

I am running Linux mint 18.3 on my Chromebook Falco, and something that I do every time I boot up is use the Chrome OS to manually boot into Linux Mint 18.3.

If I were to delete the Chrome OS, would my computer automatically boot to Linux Mint, or would my computer become useless? It would be nice to have it automatically boot to Linux Mint, but I don't want to risk anything.

Comment: Can you clarify how you are booting the Linux kernel, and if the falco is booted via uboot or coreboot. If the latter then are you using depthcharge or a different loader?

Comment: I’m not so sure Linux 18.3 is a thing... Perhaps you meant Linux Mint 18.3?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question at all. If you are running RW_LEGACY firmware you may want to look into modifying GBB flags. MrChromebox has a script for this: https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript see section 4. Set Boot Options (GBB Flags)

Comment: If you're running it through Crouton, i think it'll be difficult to preserve Mint. I personally would just backup files, put Chromebook into developer mode, and install Mint directly onto the drive. Maybe inconvenient because it'll always complaint about Chrome OS not found, though.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I have directly installed Linux Mint onto the drive and I use the Ctrl + L manual boot to select the operating system from my drive. My question is what would happen if I got rid of everything chrome related on my computer. Would my computer automatically boot onto Linux Mint.